# How to use Partitioned Orc Files in Vora

Tags: vora

We keep our Hive tables partitioned by a specific column, and save them as orc.

We would like to load this data into VORA without having to change the schemas but we get this error

**sap.hanavora.jdbc.VoraException: HL(9): Runtime error. (ORC Import ERROR: Number of Columns in ORC file is 13, but number of columns in table definition is 14**

it leaves out the Partition column.

is there a way to get VORA to read partitioned orcs?

Comment: I could reproduce the issue. We are currently investigating it. Only workaround I could come up with so far is to create a non-partitioned Hive table that is stored as non-partitioned ORC.

Comment: So this occurs because when you save a orc file to a partition table, the orc will only have the fields that are not part of a partition, Hive gets the value for those fields from the folder names...